# Array.slice on array with one element

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I'm really confused by this. If I do something like this:
    `[1].slice(1)`
it returns an empty array (in the chrome interactive console). But if I compare:
    `[1].slice(1) === []`
it's always false. So my Question is, what does [1].slice(1) really return?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is nothing to slice at index 1

Comment: writing a lispy to javascript compiler and trying to translate (rest '(1)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`===` compares objects by references.
You're comparing two *different* array objects which are both empty.

If you want to check whether an array is empty, check whether `.length === 0`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem of `slice` or `===`.

If you do `[1]==[1]`, it returns `false`.

That's because both `==` and `===` compare objects by reference

Answer (score -1):

`[] === []` also returns false. `[1].slice(1)` does in fact return `[]`

Answer (score -1):

You better check the length:

```
[1].slice(1).length; // falsey
```